# React: how to get notified when screen appears again?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

Need to get notified when user coming back from an other webpage. Unfortunatelly `useEffect` like this will not get called:

```js
function BuyTicket(props: BuyTicketProps) {

useEffect(() => {
}, [authnRes, buyTicketData, programId])
```

User action on the other website has effect on the backend state, so need to fetch backend again.

---

Shall I add a `isRequredToRefresh` state, and set it to `true` in `onClick` before or after `window.location.href` is set? But what if it will run before navigation happens?

---

What is the equivalent of iOS's `viewDidAppear` in React.js?

---

When `useEffect` without parameter should be used? I see it is constantly get called. It has also drawbacks. It can fall in infinite loop.

```js
useEffect(() => {
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window object like so :

```
const onFocus = () => {
    console.log('Im focused !')
}

useEffect(() => {
    //Add a listener on the window object
    window.addEventListener("focus", onFocus);
    //Clean listeners
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("focus", onFocus);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: How can I filter out focus events made by `select` items?

Comment: @János I'm sorry but I dont understand the question

Comment: detailed here a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73600326/how-can-focus-events-filtered-out-coming-from-select-item-changes

Comment: @János It's done =)